# how to use union while creating dynamic query

Tags: plsql

I am trying to query data from 3 diff tables by using union in a dynamic query but when i do so i dont get any compilation error, however i get the below error :

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   ORA-06512: at "XXXXXXXX", line 38

Below is the code :

```
V_Stmt_Str :='select '|| V_Mantas_Table_Seq_Id ||' from '|| Table_Name     || 'union' ||  'select '|| V_Mantas_Table_Seq_Id ||' from '|| Table_Name1     ||
'union' ||  'select '|| V_Mantas_Table_Seq_Id ||' from '|| Table_Name2;         
dbms_output.put_line('I AM HERE'); 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_Stmt_Str bulk collect into Seq_Updt_Bulk; ---- This is the line where i am getting the error.
```

Also, if i use only 1 select statement in dynamic query then it works.

Comment: have you check spaces in your sql query may be you need to print it and try to execute it.

Comment: ' union ' || ' select '||

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code I think you need to check if your sql is getting generated correctly

```
declare
v_sql varchar2(4000);
type t_emp is table of emp%rowtype;
v_emp t_emp;
begin
v_sql := 'select * from emp where account_calss =''saving'' union  select * from emp where account_calss = ''current''' ;
dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
execute immediate v_sql bulk collect into v_emp;
   for x in v_emp.first..v_emp.last
     loop
       dbms_output.put_line(v_emp(x).emp_id);
     end loop  ;
end;
```

Comment: i got the other issues resolved but when i use v_emp.first..v_emp.last  it says that first and last should be declared. Also, why cant i use count here as   1..v_emp.count

Comment: I think you should be able to everything which you have mentioned here what database and version you are using; if it is pl sql you should be able to use all. may you can paste code for more help..

Comment: Here is the code ::                                                                    V_Stmt_Str  := ' select '|| V_Mantas_Table_Seq_Id || ',' || V_Mantas_Table_Intrl_Id ||' from '|| V_Mantas_Table_Name; 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_Stmt_Str bulk collect into Details_record;
      FORALL indx IN 1..Details_record.COUNT --- Here i get the the error as COUNT not defined/First , Last not defined